# Defining length of a String/input in Gold Parser Builder

Tags: lexical-analysis, gold-parser

I'm a newbie to use Gold Parser Engine and looking for a way to limit the length of a defined `string` but I'm not finding any way to do this. Please help de do that/. Here is my code

```
    ! Welcome to GOLD Parser Builder 
"Case Sensitive"='false'
"Start Symbol" =<start>
{String Char}={Printable}
    <start>::=<Value>
        !<Value>::=<>|a<Value>|b<Value>
<Value>::=<type>name<equal>number<symbol>|<type>name<symbol>
        <type>::=int|float|char|double|boolean|String
            name={Letter}{alphanumeric}+
                <symbol>::=';'
                         <equal>::='='
number={Digit}+[.]{Digit}+|{Digit}+|{Letter}
```

Is there any way I could explain the max limit for a string. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the **parser** **wasn't designed** to easily **handle lexeme sizes** with regular expressions. You should so **check** the String size in the skeleton **program generated** from your Grammar.

To illustrate, I tried [this very trivial grammar example](http://www.goldparser.org/grammars/index.htm) from the official website:

```
"Name"         = 'String Terminal Example'
"Author"       = 'Devin Cook'
"About"        = 'This is a simple example which defines a basic string'

"Start Symbol" = <Value>

! The following defines a set of characters for the string. It contains 
! all printable characters with the exceptionof the double-quotes used 
! for delimiters. The {Printable} set does not contain newlines.

{String Ch} = {Printable} - ["]

! This statement defines the string symbol

String     = '"' {String Ch}* '"'

<Value>   ::= String
```

**`String`** is both as a **terminal token** (`String = '"' {String Ch}* '"'`) or in a rule (`<Value> ::= String`). You can **check** the token size at the terminal level.

I generated a C# one through **Calitha Engine - Custom Parser class** template, and I got a parser. Below I found the part in which you should check your String terminal token:

```
// [...]
private Object CreateObjectFromTerminal(TerminalToken token)
{
  switch (token.Symbol.Id)
    {
      // [...]

    case (int)SymbolConstants.SYMBOL_STRING :
      //String
      //todo: Create a new object that corresponds to the symbol
      return null;

      // [...]

    }
  throw new SymbolException("Unknown symbol");
}
```

According to the [Calitha Parser Engine documentation](http://www.goldparser.org/engine/1/net/van-loenhout/doc/index.html), it's possible to retrieve the text from the token: **`TerminalToken.Text`**. So why not proceeding as below:

```
case (int)SymbolConstants.SYMBOL_STRING :
    // Check size (MAX_LENGTH could be a constant you defined)
    if (token.Text.Length > MAX_LENGTH)
    {
        // handle error here
        throw new SymbolException("String too long");
    }
    return token.Text;
```

Comment: Will the C# part generate the required stuff for gold parser? As I'm not a C# developer so just need to clear that.

Comment: I was looking for an answer in GoldParser but found in C#. I'll try to do this in Java as I'm that much easy with C#.

Comment: OKAY. so for now, it is not possible limit the size using GOLD PARSER engine?

Comment: Yeah. I'm talking about meta language. Am I supposed to use engine using JAVA or C# to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: I've read the documentation but didn't find anything relevant to my problem